# Cypress - set userAgent for one test only

Tags: javascript, automation, cypress

Is there a way to change userAgent for one test only in Cypress?
I know how to do it in cypress.json file but that only sets userAgent globally for all tests and this is not what I want to achieve.
I've already tried:

```
Cypress.config('userAgent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 10_3 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/602.1.50 (KHTML, like Gecko) CriOS/56.0.2924.75 Mobile/14E5239e Safari/602.1')
```

but [it doesn't seem to update userAgent](https://docs.cypress.io/api/cypress-api/config#Notes)

Is there another way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use `cy.intercept` and change the user-agent header on the request. Reference: https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/intercept#Modifying-an-outgoing-request

Something like

```
cy.intercept('/some-path', (req) => {
  req.headers['user-agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 10_3 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/602.1.50 (KHTML, like Gecko) CriOS/56.0.2924.75 Mobile/14E5239e Safari/602.1'
})
```